# arcpy.Integrate_management failing?

Tags: arcpy, file-geodatabase, feature-class

I cannot get arcpy.Integrate_management to work.  I can run as a standalone process in ArcMap just fine, and if I copy the result as a python snippet I get:

```
arcpy.Integrate_management(in_features="SFMTA_BikeLanes #", cluster_tolerance="30 Feet")
```

Now, I try to modify this to use in my Python script, so that the process runs on a feature class that exists in my geodatabase.  I've tried:

```
#Set tolerance
ftTolerance = "30 Feet"
#arcpy.Integrate_management("G:\Shared drives\Bike Facilities Data\SF_BikeLanes.gdb\SFMTA_BikeLanes #", ftTolerance)
```

I've also tried:

```
#arcpy.Integrate_management("G:\Shared drives\Bike Facilities Data\SF_BikeLanes.gdb\SFMTA_BikeLanes", ftTolerance)
```

And, also tried:

```
# Define bike lanes feature class
bikeLanes = r'G:\Shared drives\Bike Facilities Data\SF_BikeLanes.gdb\SFMTA_BikeLanes'

arcpy.Integrate_management(bikeLanes,ftTolerance)
```

With all these, the script fails with the following error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\My Drive\GIS\Bike_Aerial_Map_Automation\Scripts\Automation_Test.py", line 184, in <module>
    arcpy.Integrate_management(bikeLanes, ftTolerance)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.7\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 2133, in Integrate
    raise e
RuntimeError: Object: Error in executing tool
```

Failed to execute (TestAutomation).

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your code looks right. You're missing the `r` for raw string in some of your paths but this isn't an issue with your paths. Maybe try running the `Repair Geometry` tool on your input and then try to `Integrate` again.

Comment: Thanks, I've defined bikeLanes using the r : bikeLanes = r'G:\Shared drives\Bike Facilities Data\SF_BikeLanes.gdb\SFMTA_BikeLanes'
So, as a last option I can try Repair Geometry?  I'm a bit baffled here why this isn't working.

Comment: What happened to # symbol, that exists in snippet?

Comment: See the first option I tried in my answer - the # symbol is there, still fails.

Comment: Anyone?!  Still unable to solve this.

Comment: Does your code work on a simple test feature class that you generate using code?  If not, then presenting that additional code will enable us to test without trying to find as much time to volunteer.